# Dynamic HTML page in WebView from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, webview

How to make a dynamic html (getting data from an sqlite database and inserting into html) and load the html in webView.

For static html my  code is working. How can I create dynamic html and load it into webview in android?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've tried so far?